# Batch How to read last digit in file name then move using that digit + 1

Tags: batch-file, filenames, windows-10

So I have a program making a file called "demo.dem" What im doing now is moving it over to another folder. I want a batch script to move the file from "C:\foo" to "C:\bar" That in itself is easy but that file will have multiply files called "demo.dem" so I need it to add a new digit to it according to what is already in the folder. Lets say I have demo 1-5 in the folder already. Then the next one needs to be "demo6.dem" Below I have some code but im no expert in batch.

```
copy C:\foo\demo.dem C:\bar\demo1.dem
del C:\bar\demo.dem
```

As you can tell this wont work. Anyone know how to make it work right?
(Edit the post if you feel you can word it better.)

Comment: Is there only a single digit at most, or could there also be numbers like `10` or higher?

Comment: I think if you want to rename the 3-digit increments, it will be much easy if you start the first number with 3-digit. ie. demo-001.dem, demo-002.dem ....

Comment: Alright, @BloodyRum, so may idea of using `dir /B /O:-N` and taking the first item will fail as `dir` sorts only by text but not in a numeric manner; if you'd follow @Paul's idea to use 3-digit increments like `001`,... the `dir` approach could work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite exactly what you seek to do but the goal would be achieved with a variable `%RANDOM%` and `%TIME%` as name, but anyway the following should do the job.

**Note:** Command `FOR` search the number surrounded by the hyphen signs `-` and dot `.` ie. demo-001.dem

So it is important to respect the renaming mask because otherwise later the script may be unable to detect the highest number.

If in case you want to change the mask, then it will take you to deal with the settings `token` and `delims`.

```
@echo off
echo List directory
dir /b C:\bar\ |sort /r

for /f "tokens=2 delims=-." %%a in ('dir /b C:\bar\demo-???.dem ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]') do (
  set "num=%%a"
  goto done
)

:done
set /a "num=%num%+1"
dir /b |sort /r
echo the highest number found is %num% -1
move c:\foo\demo.dem  c:\bar\demo-%num%.dem
dir /b C:\bar\ |sort /r
```

**Update:**
I have edited the mask of `Dir` command to list only files with a certain mask (`dir /b C:\bar\demo-???.dem`) to keep the files sorted correctly, otherwise if you have files with 1-2 digit without 0 in front that should break the sorting.

Example: suppose you sort this bunch of files: demo-009.txt, demo-010.txt, demo-3.txt; without the mask (`dir /b demo-???.txt`) you will get demo-3.txt as the highest number. So the 0 in front of the numbering is important.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most elegant way to do it since it just iterates until successful, but it should work:

```
@echo off 
set counter=1
:retry
if NOT EXIST c:\bar\demo%counter%.dem (
  move c:\foo\demo.dem c:\bar\demo%counter%.dem
 ) else (
  set /a counter=%counter%+1
  goto retry
 )
echo.
echo Created c:\bar\demo%counter%.dem!
echo.
set counter=
```